# R - Copy cell to new column if condition met

Tags: r, grepl

I am working with a sport dataset which is in a dataframe with two colums: match time and event. The event is always one of a few options (Attempt, Foul, Substitution etc...).

I would like to split up the event into new columns by the event and so want to write a loop that says "IF [CELL] contains ["event"] copy to column [3] else write [''] in column [3]"

I think I can do this with a for loop and an ifelse and grepl function.

Right now I have the following

```
for (row in 1:nrow(match_data)){

  ifelse((grepl("Attempt", match_data[row,2]), match_data[row,3] <- match_data[row,2] ,     match_data[row,3] <- '')

}
```

What I think this is saying is for each row if match_data[row, column 2] contains "attempt" then set match_data[row, column 3] to whatever is in match_data[row, column 2] else set match_data[row, column 3] to ''.

The code performs the test correctly as integers are entered into the correct rows where 'Attempt' is present. However, seemingly random integers are entered instead of the text in the matching cell.

I think this could be to do with the type of data that the functions work with but I have searched this question on here and it seems the functions I am using can work with character strings, so I don't see what problem is occurring here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you `dput()` a piece of your data? In that way we can try to reproduce it/make it better (without a for loop)

Comment: a more readable form, even keeping the `for` loop would be `match_data[row,3] <- ifelse(grepl("Attempt", match_data[row,2]),  match_data[row,2] ,  "')`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using case_when is easy to read, write and modify

```
install.packages("tidyverse")

library(tidyverse)
match_data %>% 
  mutate(newcol = case_when(event == "goal" ~ "goal"
                            , event == "own goal" ~ "goal"
                            , event == "goal" & time = "01:00" ~ "first goal"  # just an example for multiple conditions
                            , TRUE ~ "no goal"))  # else statement
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems better and I have been trying to get this to work for a while. At the moment I have simplified it to just enter '1' into the cell where an attempt has taken place so have the following: 

    match_data %>% 
      mutate(new.col = case_when(Event == "Attempt" ~ "1",
        TRUE ~ "")) 

However it isn't doing anything but also not printing any errors. Can you see any errors that I've made?

Comment: consider that R is case sensitive and other thing is you need to assign to an object to with <- to make it permanent.  match_data <- match_daya %<% mutate...

Comment: Thanks! I didn't assign it so this helped massively. After playing with it for a couple of minutes it seems like the LHS must match exactly as opposed to just containing  the value. So I've used a combination of case_when and grepl: match_data <- match_data %>% 
  mutate(Attempts = case_when(grepl("Attempt",Event) ~ "1",
    TRUE ~ ""))